# XSLT - How to select a preferred node with an 'or' condition

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<xsl:variable name="ShipToParent" select ="/Item[1]/ShipToLocation | PurchaseOrder/ShipToLocation" />
```

In the above I would like to select the first item shiptolocation even if both nodes exist. Currently it selects the purchaseorder node when both exist. I believe because it comes before the other node sequentially in the file.

Is there any way to specify a preference on an 'or' condition when both exist?

Thanks in advance,
- Steve

Comment: <xsl:variable name="ShipToParent" select ="/Item[1]/ShipToLocation | PurchaseOrder/ShipToLocation" />

Comment: Please post a complete example, including your input XML (two versions in your case, I believe) and the expected output (of each).

Comment: "*Currently it selects the purchaseorder node when both exist.*" No, you are wrong about that: it selects both. But if you're using XSLT 1.0, then `<xsl:value-of select="$ShipToParent"/>` will return the value of the first node of the selected node-set only.

Answer (score 0):

If `PurchaseOrder` always comes after the `ShipToLocation` under `Item` you could do this to get the node in the union that comes last in document order:

```
<xsl:variable name="ShipToParent" select ="(/Item[1]/ShipToLocation | PurchaseOrder/ShipToLocation)[last()]" />
```

This would not work if the order in the XML document was changed though.

Alternatively, you could put the selection of `PurchaseOrder` in a separate variable, and do something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="PurchaseOrder" select="PurchaseOrder/ShipToLocation" />
<xsl:variable name="ShipToParent" select ="/Item[1]/ShipToLocation[not($PurchaseOrder)] | $PurchaseOrder" />
```

Note that, where you do `/Item` at the start of the impression, this implies that `Item` is the root element, and therefore there is only one such element. The `[1]` condition would be unnecessary if this were the case.